# How to replace multi-line text in bash programming

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace the following text

```
text := a \
        b \
        c
```

with the following one:

```
text := d \
        e \
        f
```

in bash file.

I have tried different versions of 'sed', but none of them worked e.g.:

```
old_path='text := a \\\n\t\tb \\\n\t\tc'
new_path='text := d \\\n\t\te \\\n\t\tf'
sed -i -e "s%old_path%new_path%g" text.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not mind using **Perl** try:

```
~ ❱ perl -pe 's/ ((?=[a-z]).)/" ".chr(ord($1)+3)/eg' file
text := d \
        e \
        f 
~ ❱
```

the ASCII code for your character is: `100`, `101` and `102`
Thus if you add `3` to them they from `a b c` become `d e f`

Answer (score 1):

try with simple sed.

```
sed 's/a \\/d \\/;s/b \\/e \\/;s/c/f/'   Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Simply I am using substitute option of sed by using `s/text_which_needs_to_be_replaced/new_text`. BY separating them with semi colon will make sure we could perform multiple substitutions. substitutions are made by as per your need. Kindly do let me know if you have any queries on same.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^text := a \\/,/^\tc$/c\test := d \\\n\te \\\n\tf' file
```

Change the text in the range `'/^text := a \\/,/^\tc$/` to the required values.